# Asking about figures of speech

Tags: figures-of-speech

Is steady my knees an image and why ?and also chewing on his pipe?and shuffling of their feet? the treble of them are extracts from a prose text called "she walked alone" thank you..

Comment: Is any body here can help me???

Comment: Have you done any research? If so, please share that so we can provide a better answer.

Comment: Yeah I have done a lot but didn't find any references except the wikipedia!!so would You like me to write the whole sentences including the image or not and thank you for replying too..

Comment: Yes, please add as much context and research as you can. Thanks!

Comment: okayyy,so the text in brief is about racism and the girl (who is black)   is supposed to be prohibited from entering her school and the crowed were also against her ,shouting at her. her shock was that the guards were against her too. then came the sentence "for a moment all i could hear was the shuffling of their feet(about the crowds) .Then someone shouted "here  she comes ,Get ready"...what do you think??

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). It seems that you already got an answer you have accepted, but for future questions please include as much context as possible in the original question. If you are prompted by other users to provide more context it is better to [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/246296/edit) your question, than to provide context in the comments. Including evidence of [your own research](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is also desirable. This will help you get better answers and it will make your questions more useful to other users of the website. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think these are figures of speech as much as imagery. Can you not see an old man chewing on his pipe, or what that may look like? Have you ever seen someone shuffle their feet anxiously?

Maybe the question isn't clear.

Comment: so .. may be shuffling of their feet is a hyperbolic (Exaggeration)

Comment: Not really. Some people really do shuffle their feet when they get nervous. It basically means to awkwardly move your feet around to find a place where they are more comfortable, due to anxiety or just generally not knowing what to do with yourself.

Comment: okay,what about "chewing on his pipe"..??it is in the text about a father who is worried about his daughter because of the racism in the law that states (dark skin students shouldn't go to the school) so he was moving back and forth "chewing his pipe and he has a cigar in his hand ,but didn't light either one." according to the text.THANKS for your HELP..

Comment: Hi, Ally, welcome to the ELU :-). Your desire to help the OP is commendable, but this post is more of a comment than an answer. Please check out the [help centre](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information on this. Thanks!